# HTML5 native drag-and-drop fallback Javascript library?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Is there a library that can (with minimum hassle on my part) emulate the new [native drag-and-drop functionality](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) in HTML5 so that the technique is reasonably portable?  If so, I'm looking for a short code example of its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery ui. 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

I think it's easy enough to use.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            //blah blah blah
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I currently use.  I was just wondering if there's anything that actually completely emulates the HTML5 attributes, events, etc.  If I don't see any other answers I'll mark yours as accepted.